# How to Create a file named CNAME in the root of your Git Page repository

Tags: github-pages

Does anyone know how to 
Create a file named CNAME in the root of your Git Page repository

& Put the domain (or subdomain) into the CNAME file:

my question is regarding this issue :

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages

Comment: Just use `echo mydomain.com > CNAME`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're in a unix environment

```
cd /your/project/base/dir
touch CNAME
echo 'example.com' > CNAME
git add CNAME
git commit -m 'Added CNAME'
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking this I'm assuming the current answer will be of little help to you, so there's always the easy solution of directly creating the file from the GitHub website, by browsing to your repository and clicking the "+" in the "repository_name / +" section at the top of the page above the files list.